# in views, how to get the replacement pattern of the URL of the link field

Tags: views, 8

using the [Link module](https://www.drupal.org/project/link), i have created a view of content fields:

- Link
- Title
- Body

And i want the Title to be a clickable link to the URL of the Link field.
In D7 the links field provided for a replacement pattern for the URL as raw value but in D8 that is not available.
How can I make the Title field a clickable link with the Link URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The raw replacement pattern isn't available, but you can customize a new hidden field to be the replacement equivalent:

- Add a new link field

  - Check the **Exclude from display**, **URL only**, **Show URL as plain text** options to have your field be available.
- Add a new title field

  - Uncheck **Link to the Content**
  - Use `<a href="{{ field_MY_LINK_FIELD }}">{{ title }}</a>` in the rewrite options to render title field with a link to your link field URL

Comment: Thank you! I missed that URL only checkbox. This works good.